# SED not working with complicated string

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sed, search-and-replace

I have  a file that starts like this:

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
```

and want to replace

`error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log`

with

`error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log`

I want to use a script for that and did the following:

```
search='error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log'
replace='error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log'
for file in `find -name 'php-fpm.conf'`; do
  grep "$search" $file &> /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Search string not found in $file!"
  else
    sed -i "s#$search#$replace#" $file
  fi  
done
```

That throws this errors:

> ```
> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC the `-i` switch is an extension to the original `sed` and probably therefore implemented slightly differently in different versions.  [BSD `sed`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1) unlike [GNU `sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) requires you to explicitly use the `-e` switch to denote your command when using the `-i` switch.

Use:

`sed -i`**`-e`**`"s#$search#$replace#" $file`

as already hinted by your error message.

Writing truly portable scripts is a PITA when details such as that conspire against you.